# How to place text above an element in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Well, I want this text to be up the top roughly 20 PX from the top of the wrapper (background color) I did the margin up there but nothing happened if anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated.

**CODE**

```css
.wrapper {
 background-color: #01172c;
}

.footerid  {
 list-style: none;
}

.footerid li {
  padding-left: 125px; 
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footerid h3 {
 padding-top: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="footerid">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="logo-f.png" style=" width:80px; height:105px;"></a></li>  
   <li><h3>lol</h3></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Run the code sample in full screen to see properly.

Comment: I know he's shouting but, why the downvote? Technically it's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to indicate the `li` element about the `vertical-align` which I would set to `top` for this case

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/4zr9j3eg/

I have also disabled the `padding` property for your `h3` element which will sumup the `margin` that make the text distance from the top to `40px`

Also I changed the text-color to `color: #fff;` for debug easier

Answer (score 0):

As a general tips, you can set the wrapper to position: relative;
By doing this you can easily "control" the elements (children) inside the parent (in this case, the wrapper) with position absolute.

Example:

```
#wrapper {
   position:relative;

}

#wrapper .child {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `vertical-align: top` to `<li>`:

```
.footerid li {
     padding-left: 125px; 
     padding-top: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
     display: inline;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

and remove padding and margin from `.footerid h3`.